# Directory.GetFiles - Search pattern for file extensions

Tags: c#

I need to get all ASP files in a folder, so I wrote a code like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Folder", "*.asp", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

However, it also returns files with extension "aspx".

Is there a way to specify the end of the extension?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't test it, but maybe the pattern `*.asp?` will work

Comment: You can try IF THEN ELSE statement. IF var == "*.asp". So first write a function that checks for equality, and then pass that function as an input parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify the end of the extension?

There isn't a way to do this directly.  The best option would be to switch to `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and filter afterwards:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Folder", "*.asp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".asp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

This is because the `Directory` methods have specific behavior which prevents this from working directly. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the specified extension is exactly three characters long, the method returns files with extensions that begin with the specified extension. For example, "*.xls" returns both "book.xls" and "book.xlsx".

This is an exception to the normal search rules, but, in your case, is working against you.  Using `EnumerateFiles` streams the results, and filtering afterwards allows you to find only the proper matches.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, i don't think there's a built in way. but

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Folder", "*.asp", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => f.EndsWith(".asp")
```

should be as performant as a direct query would be. (note that `EnumerateFiles` returns an IEnumerable and is preferable to GetFiles if you don't need the files actually in an array)

Comment: Note that this will be case sensitive, which may be undesirable...

Comment: i see reed posted a better version of this answer while i typed mine, anyway.

Comment: It is true, I don't need an array!